# Spring security for some part of web site

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security, shopping-cart

I am new to spring security. I am building one application by using spring mvc 3 and hibernate.
In My application user can access all the pages without logging in. But if he is making any transaction, he will be asked for Sign in.
So can anyone help me to configure spring security only for some (transactional) requests.

It is something like online shopping cart.

Comment: You can configure Spring Security to use either URL filtering or annotations, which can be placed anywhere in your code on any method.  You would configure by setting those URLs/methods that require a logged in user to do just that...ensure the user has been authenticated.  The standard Spring Security documentation has LOTS of information about how to set that up, but seeings it's enough information to fill several volumes I will just have to defer you over to there:  http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specific URL authorisation occurs at role or authority level.

Please review this section of the spring documentation:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#authorize-requests

For example on how it is done well please review this tutorial:

http://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/

and

http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/web/